# How to make use of Hadoop MapReduce to calculate max or min of an expression with tens of variables

Tags: math, mapreduce, hadoop2

Given a math expression with tens of variables, each of which can be assigned with several candidate values. For instance, the math expression contains 20 variables, each of which can be assigned with 1, 2, or 3. In this can case there are 3^20 ways of assignment permutation.

If we want to get the max or min value among all the possible assignment permutations to the expression in brute-force manner, because of the exponential scale of assignment permutation candidates, it will definitely take way long time for a standalone computer to finish the computation. Then I thought of Hadoop MapReduce, i.e., to compute all the assignment permutations in the Mapper and then do the aggregation in the Combiner and Mapper.

A very direct but **awkward** solution is to save all the assignment permutation candidates into a file and load it to HDFS, then the Hadoop MapReduce can simply complete. But as I mentioned at the beginning, the direct input is actually only an expression, the assignment permutations should also be calculated with a program (say Java) anyway.

Therefore, hereby I would like to ask that is it possible to finish the whole process of getting the min/max value among all the assignment permutations without loading the assignment permutations to HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

Say the function you are computing is f(x)=ax^2+bx+c;
Your input file should contain values for a,b,c and x in some fixed order.

You can write a custom mapper to compute the function value and output (any key, sum computed) it to the reducer.

Then write a custom reducer that will, for every keyset find the max and min value and write it to output file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the `assignment permutation candidates` in my question actually means the assignment string as u mentioned. But I also mentioned it as an <b>awkward</b> solution, as the assignment permutation candidates are generated programmatically anyway. So is there any way for the Mappers to use the generated assignment permutations directly without storing them to the hdfs as it takes time